# how to open another activity when i click on listItem using SQLite Database and display in TextView using Intent in android

Tags: sqlite, android-intent, android-listview, onitemclick, android-bundle

In my project there three java classes they are: 
MainActivity.java,Activity2.java and DataBaseHelper.java. with two xml layouts. now i want to pass datas from MainAcitivity to Activity2 when i click on ListItem of activity_main layout and which is going to display on TextViews of act2 layout.Here i have used a sqliteDatabase with ID, NAME and DESC as a column name,
my problem is i was not able to display NAME and DESC on TextView once i Clicked on each listview, i was only able to display ID. 
I have searched for few days for solving this problem but i didn't get anything. i know its a silly and easy question but it would be very great of you if you are able to share any information and help. 
Thank you! 
i have used below code:

MainActivity.java:

```
public final static String EXTRA_NAME="com.example.verena.NAME";
   public final static String EXTRA_DESC="com.example.verena.DESC";


     private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onListClick = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            private AdapterView listView;

            public AdapterView getListView() {
                return listView;
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                /* TextView viewName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.passed);
                 TextView viewDes = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.passeddes);

                 String sName = viewName.getText().toString();
                String sDesc = viewDes.getText().toString();
                i.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME,sName);
                i.putExtra(EXTRA_DESC, sDesc);*/
                //2detail


                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
                i.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, String.valueOf(id));


                //
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                int pos = this.getListView().getSelectedItemPosition();
                Cursor c = (Cursor) this.getListView().getAdapter().getItem(pos);

                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString(EXTRA_DESC, c.getString(0));
                b.putString(EXTRA_NAME, c.getString(1));
                i.setClass(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
                i.putExtras(b);

                /* TextView desv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.passeddes);
                String  desS = desv.getText().toString();
                i.putExtra(EXTRA_DESC, desS);*/

               /* TextView viewDes = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.passeddes);
                String sDesc = viewDes.getText().toString();
                i.putExtra(EXTRA_DESC, sDesc);*/
       /*TextView viewDes = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.passeddes);
                String sDesc = viewDes.getText().toString();
                i.putExtra(EXTRA_DESC, sDesc);*/
                startActivity(i);
            }
```

Activity2.java

```
String passedVar=null;
private TextView passedNameView = null;
String passedVardes = null;
private TextView passedViewDescView = null;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act2);

    passedVar = getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_NAME);
    passedVardes= getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_DESC);
    passedView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.passed);
    passedViewDesc=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.passeddes);
    passedNameView.setText("you have click on:" + passedVar);
    passedViewDescView.setText("you hv click on:"+passedVardes);
}
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.verena/databases/";
    public static String DB_NAME = "dic.sqlite";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TB_USER = "Users";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDB;
    private Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);  
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close(){
        if(myDB!=null){
            myDB.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }

    public List<String> getAllUsers(){
        List<String> listUsers = new ArrayList<String>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c;


        try {
            c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TB_USER , null);
            if(c == null) return null;

            String name;
            c.moveToFirst();
            do {            
                name = c.getString(1);          
                listUsers.add(name);
            } while (c.moveToNext()); 
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tle99", e.getMessage());
        }


        db.close();

        return listUsers;
    }


    /***
     * Open database
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        //myDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        myDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
    public void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
        try {
            InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            String outputFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;

            while((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tle99 - copyDatabase", e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    /***
     * Check if the database doesn't exist on device, create new one
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();      

        if (dbExist) {

        } else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("tle99 - create", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------
    // PRIVATE METHODS
    // ---------------------------------------------

    /***
     * Check if the database is exist on device or not
     * @return
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase tempDB = null;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            tempDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.e("tle99 - check", e.getMessage());
        }
        if (tempDB != null)
            tempDB.close();
        return tempDB != null ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You passed the id as a string and name and description into a bundle.
So you will have to get the bundle from the intent and get your name and desc from that bundle.
The alternative is that you can pass id, name and desc as string as follows:

In your `MainActivity.java`:

```
// New Intent
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);

// Put Extras
// Put your id
i.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(id));

int pos = this.getListView().getSelectedItemPosition();
Cursor c = (Cursor) this.getListView().getAdapter().getItem(pos);

// Put Name
i.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, c.getString(0));
// Put Description
i.putExtra(EXTRA_DESC, c.getString(1));

i.setClass(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);

startActivity(i);
```

To get `id` in your `Activity2.java`, put the following line in your `onCreate` method:

```
String passedVarid = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
```

Comment: Thanks @Kapesh. i have used something like this, but it didn't work.`  public final static String EXTRA_ID="com.example.verena.ID";  but what is getListView is getter or method ? and in Activity2.java i have wrote    ` String passedVarid = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_ID");
        TextView passedIdView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.passed);
        passedIdView.setText("You!"+passedVarid);`

Comment: why do we need to use getListView and Cursor ?

Comment: getListView() is a method of ListActivity which returns you the listView of that ListActivity.
Using getListView will return you the listView and with this listView you can get the selected item and its position using the Cursor.

Comment: public final static String EXTRA_ID="com.example.verena.ID" from this Statement ID is it correct that database'd ID ?  or some other id ?

Comment: I am not able to understand what exactly your question is.
The variable EXTRA_ID is just a key to pass and retrieve the value.

Comment: thanks for reply, but my question is where  do we get variable called "ID" from  
public final static String EXTRA_ID="com.example.verena.ID" is it from SQliteDatabase Column name or any other key ? in my code i have used  public final static String EXTRA_NAME="com.example.verena.NAME";
    public final static String EXTRA_ID="com.example.verena.ID";
   public final static String EXTRA_DESC="com.example.verena.DESC"; because in my Sqlitebase I have used 3 Columns called ID, NAME and DESC.  Is the right way to call the Columns ?

Comment: Can you post your entire activity code and list row model class?

Comment: Here i post code for onListClick : private AdapterView listView; public AdapterView getListView() { return listView;  }@Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class); i.putExtra("EXTRA_ID", String.valueOf(id)); int pos = this.getListView().getSelectedItemPosition();
                Cursor c = (Cursor) this.getListView().getAdapter().getItem(pos);  i.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, c.getString(0));
i.putExtra(EXTRA_DESC, c.getString(1)); i.setClass(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);startActivity(i);}};